# Python replace multiple date columns with datetime

Tags: python, csv, datetime, pandas

I have csv files with multiple headers:

```
Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Minute' --other headers--
```

I would like to downsize these with datetime. Right now I'm doing:

```
date = datetime(year=int(d[0]), month=int(d[1]), day=int(d[2]]), hour=int(d[3]]), minute=int(d[4]]))
```

But how do I actually delete those columns and put the date column before all other columns? I eventually want the "date" to be the index in a pandas dataframe.

UPDATE:
The first five rows of one of my CSV's is:

```
"Year","Month","Day","Hour","Minute","Direct","Diffuse","D_Global","D_IR","U_Global","U_IR","Zenith"
2015,4,1,0,1,17.59,13.27,-999.00,158.94,10.75,178.97,88.700
2015,4,1,0,2,20.23,12.67,-999.00,159.45,10.68,178.99,88.726
2015,4,1,0,3,20.90,12.42,-999.00,159.77,10.55,179.03,88.752
2015,4,1,0,4,16.38,11.93,-999.00,160.68,10.47,179.45,88.777
```

I would like to have

```
"Date","Direct","Diffuse","D_Global","D_IR","U_Global","U_IR","Zenith"
DATETIMEOBJECT,17.59,13.27,-999.00,158.94,10.75,178.97,88.700
DATETIMEOBJECT,20.23,12.67,-999.00,159.45,10.68,178.99,88.726
DATETIMEOBJECT,20.90,12.42,-999.00,159.77,10.55,179.03,88.752
DATETIMEOBJECT,16.38,11.93,-999.00,160.68,10.47,179.45,88.777
```

Comment: Can you update your question with more examples in your CSV file and some code on how you read it?

Comment: @kiran.koduru does that update help?

Comment: So you want to write this information to a new CSV file? I am new to pandas myself but do you want to create a `Dataframe` object with the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the `parse_dates` parameter as the indices of the date time related columns and write a customized `date_parser` function to convert the multiple columns as a datetime column. Specify the `index_col` if you want it to be the index:

```
import pandas as pd   
from io import StringIO   
pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
"Year","Month","Day","Hour","Minute","Direct","Diffuse","D_Global","D_IR","U_Global","U_IR","Zenith"
2015,4,1,0,1,17.59,13.27,-999.00,158.94,10.75,178.97,88.700
2015,4,1,0,2,20.23,12.67,-999.00,159.45,10.68,178.99,88.726
2015,4,1,0,3,20.90,12.42,-999.00,159.77,10.55,179.03,88.752
2015,4,1,0,4,16.38,11.93,-999.00,160.68,10.47,179.45,88.777"""), 
            sep = ",", 
            parse_dates={'Date': [0,1,2,3,4]}, 
            date_parser = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format="%Y %m %d %H %M"), 
            index_col = ['Date'])
```

[image]

*Update*: 
The way `date_parser` function works according to `pd.read_csv()` docs:

> 1) Pass one or more arrays
>       (as defined by parse_dates) as arguments; 2) concatenate (row-wise) the
>       string values from the columns defined by parse_dates into a single array
>       and pass that; and 3) call date_parser once for each row using one or more
>       strings (corresponding to the columns defined by parse_dates) as arguments.

There are multiple ways this parameter can be used depending on how your customized date parser function is written, in the case given above, for instance, the second option is used, for every row, columns 0-4 are concatenated as strings separated by a whitespace and passed to `pd.to_datetime()` function and so a format of `%Y %m %d %H %M` works here.

Comment: you beat me to it.

Comment: Damn! Arguments in `Dataframes` I did not know existed.

Comment: and to pass a whole CSV file, just replace "StringIO()" with the name of the CSV? @Psidom

Comment: Yes. That's where the file name should go.

Comment: can you briefly explain the "lambda" in the "date_parser" line? @Psidom